# iOS: Measure call quality/signal Strength

Tags: ios, iphone

I am building an app like RootMetrics - Cell Phone Coverage link https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cell-phone-coverage-map/id399701910 here
or OpenSignal - https://itunes.apple.com/app/opensignal/id598298030

I need help to understand how they measure call/voice quality. As far as I understand such APIs are private and apps using them, would not be authorized on App Store. Can anyone tell me how to measure signal strength in such cases.

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe this is possible without the use of private API:s. And as you said, Apple's bots will probably (definitely) find out when you try to upload the app to App Store.

If you still want to use a private API, this method for measuring carrier signal strength should to the trick:

```
-(int) getSignalStrength() {
    void *libHandle = dlopen("/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony", RTLD_LAZY);
    int (*CTGetSignalStrength)();
    CTGetSignalStrength = dlsym(libHandle, "CTGetSignalStrength");
    if( CTGetSignalStrength == NULL) 
        NSLog(@"Could not find CTGetSignalStrength");
    int result = CTGetSignalStrength();
    dlclose(libHandle);
    return result;
}
```

I would suggest taking the average value of about 10 measurements since I believe that these can differ a lot.